# Avs FastSimpleImport - Super Attribute Option Price

Tags: magento-1.8, import, products, avs-fastsimpleimport

i have setup an product import with AVS fastsimpleimport and have some trouble to get  the right fields or syntax for configurable option value prices. What i want to do is price changes to the options similar to this:

[image]

so, how can i set the option price thruh the import array?

my importdata so far (just for e.g):

```
....                
$data[$key] = array(
                'store'                   => array('default'),
                '_product_websites'       => array('base'),
                'sku'                     => isset($information[0]) ? $information[0] : null,                        
                '_attribute_set'          => 'Default',
                '_type'                   => 'configurable',
                '_category'               => isset($information[39]) ? explode(',',$information[39]) : null,
                'price'                   => isset($information[22]) ? str_replace(',', '.', $information[22]) : null,       
//                'special_price'           => isset($product['special_price']) ? $product['special_price'] : null,
                'weight'                  => isset($information[16]) ? $information[16] : null,                      
                'name'                    => (isset($information[0]) && isset($information[4])) ? utf8_encode($information[4]." - ".$information[0]." ".$information[5]." ".$information[6]) : null, 
                'description'             => isset($information[7]) ? $information[7] : null,                        
                'short_description'       => (isset($information[5]) && isset($information[6])) ? utf8_encode($information[5]." ".$information[6]) : null, /
                'status'                  => '1',
                'visibility'              => '4',
                'tax_class_id'            => '1',
                'qty'                     => '99',
                'is_in_stock'             => '1',
....
```

thanks in advance

EDIT ----

i edited my code but get errors. here is it:

```
        // create variants first 
        $simples = $this->createVariants($data, $additionalInformations);
        $simple_sku = array();

            // create the values for each simple product
            foreach($simples as $simple)
            {

                $data[$key]['_super_products_sku'] =  $simple['sku'];
                $data[$key]['_super_attribute_code'] =  array('material','schirme');
                $data[$key]['_super_attribute_option'] =  $simple['schirme'];
                $data[$key]['_super_attribute_price_corr'] =  $simple['price'];

        }

    // merge the data arrays
    array_unshift($data, $simple);
                print_r($data);
```

log output:

```
[_super_products_sku] => AF4125-780.RK25
            [_super_attribute_code] => Array
                (
                    [0] => size
                    [1] => size
                )

            [_super_attribute_option] => label
            [_super_attribute_price_corr] => 340
```

but seems to not bee right

Comment: Have a look at Vinai's slides at netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf. They cover custom options and configurable products well. For everything else, see http://www.integer-net.com/2012/04/04/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/.

Comment: it looks to be a bit tricky. i found this ressource here: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/133. its a bit my issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the solution. Its a bit tricky with all the arrays but this works for me:

```
       $super_attributes = array('size', 'color');

        // !!!super attribute option price
        foreach($super_attributes as $superattribute)
        {
            foreach($simples as $simple) // simples are the variations, see above
            {

                    $data[$key]['_super_attribute_code'][] =  $superattribute; 
                    $data[$key]['_super_products_sku'][] =  $simple['sku'];
                    $data[$key]['_super_attribute_option'][] =  $simple[$superattribute];                                              
                    $data[$key]['_super_attribute_price_corr'][] =  $simple['price'];

            }

        }
```

with this code you get the formated options for the super attributes + pricing, e.g:

```
       [_super_attribute_code] => Array
            (
                [0] => size
                [1] => color
            )

        [_super_products_sku] => Array
            (
                [0] => sku-1
                [1] => sku-2
            )

        [_super_attribute_option] => Array
            (
                [0] => label size
                [1] => label color
            )

        [_super_attribute_price_corr] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 140
            )
```

thats it. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to use _super_attribute_code, _super_attribute_option and _super_attribute_price_corr for every option i wanted a price correction for.

From your data-array it looks like you are using the nested-array-adapter so you have to take care and have the keys of the corresponding options/prices/attributes the same because they are internally split into different rows.

Comment: thanks nils. i found allready out which fields i need. now its about the right array syntax